# `ruby -S rake spec` works fine from command line, but not when executing `sh "ruby -S rake spec"` from Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, rakefile

I have the following directory structure:

```
parent/
    Rakefile
    child/
        Rakefile
```

My Rakefiles look like this:

```
# parent/Rakefile
task :spec do
  Dir.chdir(File.join File.dirname(__FILE__), 'child') do
    sh "ruby -S rake spec"
  end 
end

# parent/child/Rakefile
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new :spec do |task|
  task.rspec_opts = %w(--color --format documentation)
end
```

If I execute `ruby -S rake spec` inside `parent/child` the specs run correctly. If I execute `rake spec` inside `parent/` I get the following error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rspec/core/rake_task
/workplace/max/parent/child/Rakefile:2:in `require'
/workplace/max/parent/child/Rakefile:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
```

It's worth noting that rspec is in the bundle for `parent/child` but rspec is not in the bundle of `parent/`

Comment: Just to add another data point, `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=true rake spec` works. I think the problem is that the bundle is not being included when running Rake.

Comment: I've also tried adding `Bundler.setup` to my Rakefile, which did not work.